# Incorrect syntax when using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have trouble executing the dynamic sql returned by the select procedure.
Below is a sample of my code:

```
DECLARE 
    @ID int
  , @Query nvarchar(max)
SET @ID = CONVERT(int, '[P:Field_ID]')
SET @Query = 
    (
        SELECT
            FF.[External_Source_Query]
        FROM WF_Form_Field FF
            LEFT JOIN WF_Field F ON
                FF.[Field_ID] = F.[ID]
        WHERE
            FF.[External_Source_Query] IS NOT NULL
        AND F.[ID] = @ID
    )

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@Query)
```

I am receiving an error saying Incorrect syntax near '@Query'.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use brackets:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```

You would use brackets if you we're doing a plain `EXEC`:

```
EXEC(@Query)
```

However, I also fail to see how this line will ever produce a correct result:

```
SET @ID = CONVERT(int, '[P:Field_ID]')
```

Since I can see no rational way to interpret the string `[P:Field_ID]` as an integer.

Comment: Thanks Damien, that worked. The '[P:Field_ID]' is used by our own internal framework to pass JSON parameters to sql. So in this case, '[P:Field_ID]' would have been passed as a string parameter.